# Change the dimension of data set from (32,32,3,10000) to (10000,32,32,3) for training the CNN

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, reshape

I have got a training data set with dimensions (32, 32, 3, 10000) testing dataset with dimensions (32, 32, 3, 1000). I am trying to build a cnn model to predict the image. I tried below architecture.

```
  model = keras.Sequential(layers = [
  keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3), input_shape=(32,32,3)),
  keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3), padding='same',activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'),
  keras.layers.Flatten(),
  keras.layers.Dense(units = 32, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(units = 32, activation='softmax')
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_label, batch_size=10, epochs=3, verbose=1, validation_data=(test_images, test_label))
```

Then it gives me an error

```
 ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 32
  y sizes: 10000
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

Then I tried reshaping the train and test data by changing the fitting line as below

```
history = model.fit(train_images.reshape(10000,32,32,3), train_label, batch_size=10, epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_data=(test_images.reshape(1000,32,32,3), test_label))
```

Then the program runs but I am confused that when I tried plotting an image from the data set it is showing like below.

[image]

[image: I guess the image is the one I should get.]

What's wrong with reshaping the data set?
How can I make a cnn model with this dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need transpose, not reshape:

```
train_images.transpose([3, 0, 1, 2])
```

Reshape takes all your data in bulk and start to change amount of elements each dimension. Transpose change hierarchy of dimensions but saves data in place. Detailed explanation: [https://lihan.me/2018/01/numpy-reshape-and-transpose/#:~:text=numpy.,format%20array%20into%20that%20shape.&text=Transpose%2C%20on%20the%20other%20hand,in%20a%20higher%20dimensional%20setting](https://lihan.me/2018/01/numpy-reshape-and-transpose/#:%7E:text=numpy.,format%20array%20into%20that%20shape.&text=Transpose%2C%20on%20the%20other%20hand,in%20a%20higher%20dimensional%20setting).